# Passing function parameters into class function pointer parameters

Tags: c++, function, pointers, arduino

Trying to make a class in Arduino that can handle millis delay easily.
My idea is to make a class, where you can pass inside the function you want to run and the time for delay.
Calling `run` method checks if the delay time has passed and it can run the function.

```
MillisTimer MT_measureAndWrite(measureAndWrite, 1000);
```

`measureAndWrite` function has `void` return type and zero parameters.
I was able to do this. This was running fine.

However I ran into a problem where I want to use a function with parameters.
I tried to use template class but no luck

```
MillisTimer<float, float, float, float> MT_LCDrefresh(LCDrefresh(1.5,2.5,3.5,4,5), 500);


template <class A = void, class B = void, class C = void, class D = void>
class MillisTimer
{
private:

    void(*mFunc0)(A,B,C,D);
    const uint16_t mDelayTime;
    unsigned long mPreviousTime;
    const bool mDebugMode;

public:
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
        mFunc0 = func;
        mPreviousTime = millis();
    }
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(A), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
        mFunc0 = func;
        mPreviousTime = millis();
    }
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(A, B), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
        mFunc0 = func;
        mPreviousTime = millis();
    }
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(A, B, C), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
        mFunc0 = func;
        mPreviousTime = millis();
    }
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(A, B, C, D), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
        mFunc0 = func;
        mPreviousTime = millis();
    }

    void run() {
        if (millis() - mPreviousTime >= mDelayTime)
        {
            if (mDebugMode) Serial.println("uId: " + String((unsigned long)this) + " millis: " + String(millis() + "ms"));
            mPreviousTime = millis();
            mFunc0();
        }
    }
};
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
class MillisTimer
{
private:
    void (*mFunc)();
    const uint16_t mDelayTime;
    unsigned long mPreviousTime;
    const bool mDebugMode;

public:
    MillisTimer(void(*func)(), uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) : mDelayTime(delayTime), mDebugMode(debugMode), mPreviousTime(millis())
    {
        mFunc = func;
    }

    void run() {
        if (millis() - mPreviousTime >= mDelayTime)
        {
            if (mDebugMode) Serial.println("uId: " + String((unsigned long)this) + " millis: " + String(millis() + "ms"));
            mPreviousTime = millis();
            mFunc();
        }
    }
};

MillisTimer MT_measureAndWrite(measureAndWrite, 1000);
MillisTimer MT_LCDfrissit([](){LCDfrissit_(U_Akku, Teljesitmeny, U_Atlag, U_Korrekt);},500);
```

Comment: "However I ran into a problem where I want to use a function with parameters. I tried to use template class but no luck": How did you try to call the function? What was the error you got? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The code I wrote down was far from compiling and gave a lot of errors and I thought there was no meaning to post the errors. Jarod42 wrote a good solution. My final solution that's good enough for me to get the job done is added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass directly functor to your class:

```
template <class F>
class MillisTimer
{
private:
    F mF;
    const uint16_t mDelayTime;
    unsigned long mPreviousTime = 0;
    const bool mDebugMode;

public:
    MillisTimer(F f, uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false) :
        f(f), mDelayTime(delayTime), mPreviousTime(millis()), mDebugMode(debugMode)
    {
    }

    void run() {
        if (millis() - mPreviousTime >= mDelayTime)
        {
            if (mDebugMode) {
                Serial.println("uId: " + String((unsigned long)this)
                               + " millis: " + String(millis() + "ms"));
            }
            mPreviousTime = millis();
            mF();
        }
    }
};

template <typename F>
MillisTimer<F> MakeMillisTimer(F f, uint16_t delayTime, bool debugMode = false)
{
    return {f, delayTime, debugMode};
}
```

With usage:

```
auto MT_measureAndWrite = MakeMillisTimer(&measureAndWrite, 1000);
auto MT_LCDrefresh =  = MakeMillisTimer([](){ LCDrefresh(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 5); }, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I got better understanding how to use lambda/function pointers/templates together.